# Android, Scala and Proguard

Tags: android, scala, proguard

After running headfirst into as many problems as there are permutations of the set of Android command-line tools, I finally managed to compile a mix of Scala and Java source code into a usable apk.

As many suggest, I used `proguard` to squeeze the Scala library through the `dex` tool. The problem is this:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 29 seconds
```

One minute and a half. We're talking about an application with Hello-World complexity here. I don't think I can develop like that. I'm gonna need to take meditation classes.

This is the `proguard` configuration:

```
-injars ${out.absolute.dir}/classes:${scala-library.jar}(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,!library.properties)
-outjars ${out.absolute.dir}/classes.min.jar
-libraryjars ${android.jar}
-dontwarn
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

Is there a way to speed up the proguard step?

**Edit**: I'm running this in a pretty decent dual-core, 3GB ram machine, on top of 64-bit Linux. A run of `ant compile` (`scalac`/`javac`) takes 3 seconds. A full `ant install` takes 1:30, as described above. It's the `proguard` step that "freezes", according to the output, most likely because of the scala/android runtime lib sizes.

Comment: we need some more details, for example you machine set-up..ie number of cpus, ram, etc.

Comment: supposedly the compiler would be the bottleneck which compiler are you using?

Comment: See also: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#scala. I think it's not the compiler being bottlenecked, but just the 8.5 Mb of scala runtime takes quite a while to read in and pack.

Comment: You do not need the proguard step on test runs. You may also avoid proguard for tests, as long as the emulator can handle the large size.

Comment: @Daniel - sadly, proguard is always necessary - the libraries are too large to fit into Dalvik's "dex" file format :-( This is just as true for the emulator as for a real device. And you should be aware that there's no sensible solution at all for 2.9.1 :-( See http://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate/browse_thread/thread/125dd06446c8c078 for a description of why.

Comment: Compile speed significantly improves if you move your scala libs to the AVD and skip the proguard step. check [this](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/emulator-android-sdk.html) and [this](http://scala-forum.org/read.php?4,503,503#msg-503)

Comment: @Jamil that sounds pretty reasonable, I'll give it a look and come back!

Comment: @Paul You shouldn't need to run tests in dex. Tests can be run in plain JVM bytecode -- the dependencies are mocked, and there's no UI.

Comment: @Daniel - sorry, I'm confused. The emulator can't run bytecode directly AFAIK, only dex files. You can run tests outside the emulator with Robolectric, which is an excellent choice for some code, but not always appropriate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Paul Tests. Unit tests -- you don't need to test business logic with the emulator, because it is just plain Scala code.

Comment: @Daniel - OK, got you. Your comment "as long as the emulator can handle the large size" confused me :-)

Comment: @Paul Sorry, that was about not running proguard but still generating dex, which you have corrected me about.

Comment: Try AndroidProguardScala if you use Eclipse.  https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala  It speeds up the cycle by caching previous proguard runs and using the cached versions if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working via android Ant builds is probably not the right way to go about this.

The current "best advice" is to use SBT with the

- proguard (https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin) and
- android (https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin)

plugins.

Comment: Agreed. But be aware of the issues with 2.9.1 I mention in my comment above. It is possible to install the Scala (2.8.x) libraries on a device and avoid the proguard step, as described here: http://zegoggl.es/2011/07/how-to-preinstall-scala-on-your-android-phone.html but be aware that there are some issues (not yet fixed as far as I know) with the most recent version of the Android SDK.

Comment: I haven't tried SBT yet, but I don't understand how it would help. Doesn't it automatically do the same proguard run I scheduled manually?

Comment: Note that proguarding is now part of the sbt android plugin (don't get afraid of the misleading and incorrect license message it displays, see https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/issues/129)

Answer (score 6):

ProGuard takes a lot longer to shrink the Scala 2.9.1 library than the Scala 2.8.1 library (54 seconds vs. 13 seconds, for 8.5 MB vs. 6.2 MB). Either the structure of the library classes has changed fundamentally, or some new classes are causing excessive computations. I'll have to figure out if ProGuard or its configuration can be improved for this case. For now, you might be able to work with Scala 2.8.1.

I'm assuming your ProGuard configuration also contains the required options for Android and for Scala, as discussed in the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html). If you are using the regular Android build process, the input (`classes`, `libs`) and libraries (`android.jar`) are already specified for you in the Ant build file, and you don't need to specify them again in the ProGuard configuration file. Reading them twice will just take time and generate many warnings (which you have switched off completely -- it's safer to switch them off selectively).

Comment: Despite taking longer, I'm running into strange problems with Proguard and Scala 2.9.1. After obfuscation the shrinkin removes basic scala stuff like Traversable or HashMap.foreach etc. So it will cause the program to fail with ClassNotFoundError class axy (etc..) proguard_map points axy to above mentioned and used Scala objects.

Comment: @vertti A processed HelloWorld program (combined with Scala 2.9.1) runs fine when I try it, so I'll need more details about your code. If you post a separate question here or in ProGuard's Help forum, I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but my current game is around 6000 lines of scala and ripping out a functional part that still breaks proguard might prove difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your help (at proguard bug tracker). To others: My problems turned out to be related to Windows file system, not Scala (see last entry at: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/limitations.html)

Comment: See this: http://scalandroid.blogspot.com/2012/03/proguard-performance-and-scala-versions.html - Scala 2.10 will rock again with proguard

Comment: @Eric If you're worried about running into the reserved device names on Windows, you can use the \\?\ prefix on filenames to get around that. Or just exclude them from the filename generator; there aren't very many.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a rooted phone and only want to test on this you can install the scala libs directly on your phone so you don't need the proguard step anymore:

https://github.com/jrudolph/scala-android-libs